# Should a delay be expected to cause deadlock?

Tags: arduino-mega, timers

I have made a simple program using the `int main() {}` function. It has a delay in it. It is evident the code before the delay is running, but the delay never seems to time out and let the next instructions through. Is this by design?

If I rename the method and call it exactly once from the `loop() {}` function though, it does work.

**Edit:**

The code borrowed the 'main()' function and I suppose redefined it:

```
int main() { 
    Forward();
    delay(3000);
    Reverse();
}

void Forward() {
    //...
}

void Reverse() {
    //... 
}
```

I can see this redefinition of `main()` could cause some serious issues based on the answer below.

Comment: We would need to see the code in question in order to give a full answer.

Comment: main() suggest this isn't normal Arduino.

Comment: Arduino programs don't use `main`, they use `loop`

Comment: What value for delay are you using? `delay(999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999);` will cause a fairly large problem (if the variable even is that big). | @Cyber It must be another language/bare C. It's weird that it compiled...

Comment: First, no, delay can't deadlock, because there are no *threads* to deadlock on the Arduino. Second, you wouldn't be able to build a sketch containing a redefinition of `main` (and you don't sound experienced enough to bypass the IDE). Show the simplest code that reproduces the problem. I'm guessing the problem will be very obvious to readers here.

Comment: If you don't use Arduino standard `main()` then you cannot expect using Arduino functions like `delay()` because these rely on timer initialization performed by `main()`.

Comment: @jippie look at my answer below, you'll see the code of `delay()` depends on `micros()` which itself is based on Timer0. At least the code is so in Arduino 1.05 libraries. You must be talking about `delayMicroseconds()` which is a different beast.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Why would they do that? The standard and highly optimized delay (both ms and us) routines are in the standard AVR libraries :-s `/usr/lib/avr/include/util/delay.h`

Comment: @jippie Why? I have no idea; they must have a good reason I guess ;-)

Comment: @jfpoilpret I think it must have changed over software releases. The `delay.h` version can only be passed a static parameter, whereas 'your' `Arduino.h` version can be passed a changing parameter. I remember from when I was a young boy that you couldn't pass a variable to `delay();`. With this code you obviously can.

Comment: @annon this code won't compile as `delay()` expects an `unsigned long` which is "only" 32 bits. Also the OP mentioned that it worked in `setup()`, I guess this was with the same duration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't seem to use standard Arduino stuff since you defined your own `main()` which is normally avoided when programming Arduino.

If you take a look at Arduino provided `main()` (in **hardware/cores/arduino/main.cpp**), you'll see how it is defined:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void)
{
    init();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Did you notice the `init()` function call at the beginning?

Its code is defined in **hardware/cores/arduino/wiring.c**; what it does is setup all timers used by Arduino functions, in particular a timer that is needed by `delay()`.

In the same **wiring.c** file, you can also find the definition of `delay()`:

```
void delay(unsigned long ms)
{
    uint16_t start = (uint16_t)micros();

    while (ms > 0) {
        if (((uint16_t)micros() - start) >= 1000) {
            ms--;
            start += 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

This will turn into an infinite loop if `micros()` always return the same value, and it does so if `init()` has never been called before.

This is what happens with your code.

Comment: This means `delay();` won't work with interrupts disabled.

Comment: @jippie yes, that's why you should never call it from an ISR or a function that has disabled interrupts.

Comment: Cheers jfpoilpret, I was actually surprised when I borrowed the name `main` and found it was recognised same as with general c programs so I ran with it, since, I only wanted this instruction run once anyway. Your answer has given a good hint as to the architecture and I'll be able to work from there. Apologies for taking such a hack approach..!

Comment: @JCollins no need to apologize, hacking is part of learning and experience eventually :-) Glad you can proceed from here.